# Extract substring from string (time from ping reply in C using string library)

Tags: c, ping

Just wanted to get the time value. No straight forward answer looking at the C library table.

```
64 bytes from 58.27.61.104: icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=45.5 ms
```

Comment: wouldn't be simpler with AWK or something ? does it have to be in C ?

Comment: `scanf()` or `sscanf()`? (Standard IO library)

Comment: Use `strstr` to locate `time=` and then `atof` to read the value.

Comment: I am writing in C. Ok, but strstr only return a value. How ti go from there?

Comment: Uh, that would be the thing I said right after `strstr`.

Comment: I am using `strstr`, thanks. But I need to remove the chars before I can `atof`. Is there something in library that I can use to get **nth** character onwards up to **mth** character? Or I'd just use for loop and extract by array.

Comment: @Jongware better use `strtod()` instead of `atof()`.

Comment: @EmmaAhmadSirajudin No, you don't need to "remove the characters". Both `atof()` and the (**strongly preferred**) `strtod()` stop automatically when they encounter the end of the number (e. g. they reach a whitespace or other non-number character).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the standard `string.h` function `strstr` to locate a substring inside a string. This returns, when found, a pointer to the first character of the located substring. Add the substring length so its point to the character immediately following that substring.

Then use `strtod` to convert the ASCII string to a double value. `strtod` ignores leading whitespace and will use the current locale:

> .. leading white-space characters in the string
>        (as defined by the isspace(3) function) are skipped.  The decimal point
>        character is defined in the program's locale (category LC_NUMERIC).
>   (from `man strtod` on OS X)

A robust program should check for invalid input (i.e., no digits follow `time=`, or the value  cannot be represented in a `double`), but error checking has been omitted here for clarity.

In code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char *input = "64 bytes from 58.27.61.104: icmp_seq=3 ttl=59 time=45.5 ms";
    char *looking_for = "time=";
    char *pos_of_time;
    double the_time;

    pos_of_time = strstr (input, looking_for);
    if (pos_of_time == NULL)
    {
        printf ("No match for 'time=' found\n");
    } else
    {
        /* pos_of_time points to the 't' */
        /* we need to look beyond the string */
        pos_of_time += strlen(looking_for);
        the_time = strtod (pos_of_time, NULL);
        printf ("time is %f\n", the_time);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which shows the output as expected:

```
time is 45.500000
```